# How to implement a Dispose method on class when postback happens

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection, postback, dispose

I have a class that Inherits from a class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page. Generally it looks like this:

```
public class ToolPage : System.Web.UI.Page
public partial class EmailAnswer : ToolPage
```

This EmailAnswer class has some custom objects for example:

```
private EmailTemplate _emailTemplate
{
    get
    {
        return (EmailTemplate)ViewState["_emailTemplate"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["_emailTemplate"] = value;
    }
}
```

This object implements IDisposable, so I added a code like this to my EmailAnsewr class:

```
public sealed override void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (_emailTemplate != null)
            _emailTemplate.Dispose();
    }
    if (_groupsEmailTargets!= null)
        _groupsEmailTargets= null;
    if (_emailAttachments != null)
        _emailAttachments = null;
}
```

This object_emailTemplate is loaded to ViewState only on the first Page_load event, and later when I'm submitting the form _emailTemplate is used. Now on the first post back I'm loosing this object because a call to Dispose is made.

So how this dispose implementation should be done?

Comment: Do you *need* to dispose it?

Comment: Don't just randomly dispose things unless you have a reason to. Unless you are calling a COM component, you don't usually need to.

Comment: This object (_emailTemplate) uses third party component with Database access, and few other objects that implements IDisposable so I thought that I should dispose it

Comment: So next question, "on the first post back", so you're on different requests? Does the object live between requests? Or are you constructing a new one on each request?

Comment: Yes it lives between requests and sometimes it is used. This page has several controls that causes post back but only some of them use this object.

Comment: So then don't dispose of it until you're done with it then?

Comment: The object is no longer needed when user closes the popup window with this control, so I think the proper implementation would be overriding the Dispose class and calling _emailTemplate.Dispose() then. Anyway this is the general question how to handle sommething like that when object need to be alive during postback but also they're holding some resources and should be Disposed when Page is Disposing.

Comment: A Disposable object should not be placed in the ViewState.

Comment: It's easy to say but how to keep them alive during postbacks? For now I'm just using session.